# How to write a unit test for a method, which creates database table on the fly?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

**tl;dr;**. I have a method for creating new database table on the fly, and I want to write a unit test for it. Unfortunately, test runner does not perform rollback after tests in a proper way, and the table still remains in the DB after tests finished. What should I do?

#### Long story:

*I am not very familiar neither with Java Persistence nor with Java Spring, so, if you found current solution ugly (as for me, it is rather ugly), please, tell me how to improve it - I will very appreciate your opinion.*

I have a `SysDatastoreService` with the following implementation of `addStaticDatastore` method.

```
@Service
public class SysDatastoreServiceImpl implements SysDatastoreService {
    @Autowired
    private SysDatastoreRepository datastoreRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Optional<SysDatastore> addStaticDatastore(String name, String tableName, String ident, Long ord) {
        String createTableSql = PostgresTableSqlBuilder.createTableInPublicSchemaWithBigintPkAndFkId(
                tableName,
                SysObject.TABLE_NAME,
                Optional.of(SysObject.ID_COLUMN_NAME)).buildSql();

        Optional<SysDatastore> sysDatastore = Optional.empty();

        try(
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement()
        ) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Savepoint beforeTableCreation = connection.setSavepoint();

            try {
                statement.execute(createTableSql);
                sysDatastore = Optional.ofNullable(
                        datastoreRepository.save(new SysDatastore(name, tableName, DatastoreType.STATIC, ident, ord)));
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(!sysDatastore.isPresent()) {
                connection.rollback(beforeTableCreation);
            } else {
                connection.commit();
            }
        } catch(SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sysDatastore;
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, I receive new connection from `DataSource` and try to create new table. In success, I will create a new entry in the `SysDataStoreRepository`, and, if this fails, I will perform a rollback for the table creation.

There are some disadvantages of current approach, one of them is that table creation and entry insertion operates on separate connections (am I right?).

But I have some problem while writing a unit test. This is what I tried:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml")
public class SysDatastoreServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private SysDatastoreService sysDatastoreService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    public void testAddStaticDatastore() throws Exception {
        Optional<SysDatastore> sysDatastore =
                sysDatastoreService.addStaticDatastore("New static datastore", "new_datastore_table",
                                                       "NEW_DATASTORE_TABLE", 42L);

        assertTrue(sysDatastore.isPresent());
        assertEquals("New static datastore", sysDatastore.get().getName());
        assertEquals("NEW_DATASTORE_TABLE", sysDatastore.get().getIdent());
        assertEquals("new_datastore_table", sysDatastore.get().getTableName());
        assertEquals(DatastoreType.STATIC, sysDatastore.get().getDynType());
        assertEquals(42L, sysDatastore.get().getOrd().longValue());

        assertTrue(dataSource.getConnection()
                             .getMetaData()
                             .getTables(null, null, sysDatastore.get().getTableName(), null)
                             .next());
    }
```

This test seems pretty easy: I just compare all the fields, and then checks database for a new table.

However, this test fails when I run it twice or more times. Looking at the database I noticed, that the table `new_datastore_table` still remained in the schema. I guess, it was not rollbacked properly because of hand-written transaction and raw sql execution, but I am not sure.

**Question**: How should I write a test case for this method in a proper way? And, in case if the current approach is fundamentally wrong, how it should be changed?

*Side notes*: I use PostgreSQL database, and it cannot be replaced with non-relational database.

Comment: I am not sure that the @Transactional will be followed on the class in a test, try putting it on the actual method (`testAddStaticDatastore`). Works fine for my tests here, as the transaction gets rolled back then.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz, unfortunately, this does not work for me. I have other test classes with top-level `@Transactional` annotation, and it behaves as expected. But, of course, they do not call methods with hand-written transaction management.

Comment: Can't you just put a teardown method that will remove the database?

Comment: @Kayaman, yes, sure, but this seems to be a fix for the *effect*, but not for the *cause*. I am afraid of possible bugs in the future.

Comment: It's a pretty standard construct to have setup -> test -> teardown, with a test database being built at setup and then torn down. Just remember that you might be trying to make your test cleverer than it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a CREATE TABLE is a DDL statement, not a DML one. That means that a rollback will not delete the table. If you want to clean your database, you must explicitely remove it in a `@After` or `@AfterClass` method.

But do you really need to do the tests on the PostgreSQL database? Spring has great support for [in memory databases](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-embedded-database-support) and the default embedded database is HSQL which has a pretty good support for postgresql syntax. Provided you have no complex statement, it could be enough and avoids cluttering the main database for (potentially destructive) unit tests.

You could create the database in a `@BeforeClass` method. Here is an oversimplified example:

```
private static DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() throws Exception {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("path/to/package/defaults.sql"));
    dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(); 
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:pgtest;sql.syntax_pgs=true");
    dataSource.setUsername("SA");

    Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
    assertNotNull(con);
    populator.populate(con);
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, current project does not have well-defined database scheme in Java (ugh! this makes me angry all the time I think of it), and, therefore, `HSQL` could not be used *right now* (I have plans for code refactoring). Thank you, I sure, this is the right solution. Just one more question:  _"a rollback will not delete the table"_ - so, using `connection.rollback(beforeTableCreation);` in the `addStaticDatastore` method is also invalid? As far as I read, Postgres supports transactions for `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @soon If you have a .sql file that creates the database schema it is enough. My example uses a `ResourceDatabasePopulator` to pass a (here one but might be many) sql script to initialize the new database. For second question, the rollback is not invalid simply AFAIK it has no effects on DDL statements: you can only rollback insert, update, delete (and lock).